# .load() sem substituir, apenas adicionar

Tags: jquery

Preciso usar o .load(), o problema é que ele substitui o conteúdo de onde eu marco para ele adicionar o que carregou.
Não posso criar uma nova div para que ele adicione o conteúdo carregado.

Existe algum jeito de especificar que é pra ele carregar na div selecionada mas sem substituir o que já tem nessa div? Ele carrega e adiciona, não substitui.

Eu pensei em algo como
`$('div').append(function(){
$('div').load('local')`
mas não funciona.

Isso foi no intuito de não precisar usar o include do php.

Comment: Usa `$.ajax` e depois `.append` dentro da callback `success`

Answer (score 2):

Você pode solicitar a pagina por AJAX ([`$.get()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/), por exemplo com jQuery) e no *callback success* adiciona-la a página com bem entender, algo similar a isso:

```
$.get('ajax/test.html', function(data){
    $('#result').prepend(data);
});
```

> Fonte: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8808168/2290538

Para adicionar o conteúdo sem remover o que havia anteriormente você pode utilizar:

- [`.prepend()`](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/): Inseri o conteúdo especificado por parâmetro no inicio do conjunto de elementos;
- [`.append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/): Inseri o conteúdo especificado por parâmetro no fim do conjunto de elementos;

Comment: Apenas para complementar, você pode usar o '.append()'.
.prepend() = adiciona o conteúdo antes dos demais conteúdos da sua div.
.append() = adiciona o conteúdo depois dos demais conteúdos da sua div

Comment: É que no caso a div #result seria a tag "head" usaeuhua é que no caso eu quero colocar o favicon nesse "test.html" para que eu altere apenas nele e altere em todas as páginas html. Queria ver se funcionava por esse método.

Comment: @ThomasLima, estava editando com essas informações, hehe. Confira a edição e obrigado pela dica. =)

Comment: @Undeath, `$('#result')` em seu exemplo da pergunta seria o seletor: `$('div')`.

Comment: @Fernando, foi mal... acho q adicionei o comentário durante a sua edição. Mas vlw =)

Comment: @Undeath, pode tentar no _head_, ele vai adicionar, só não sei se a renderização vai ficar de acordo com o esperado, mas acho que sim! Tente e comente.

Comment: Mas não resultou... Simplesmente não funcionou...

Comment: @Undeath, como você tentou?

Comment: Adicionei dentro da tag head do meu index.html o seguinte codigo: <script type="text/javascript" src="js/head.js"></script> e dentro do head.js: $.get('html/head.html', function(data){
    $('head').prepend(data);
}); e dentro do head.html: <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" >

Comment: @Undeath, o jQuery tem que ter sido importado antes e estar devidamente carregado, observe o console se há algum erro! [Observe como utilizar o jQuery corretamente](https://learn.jquery.com/about-jquery/how-jquery-works/).

Comment: O footer e header aparecem com esse sistema de load. Não há problema com eles pq eu defini divs exclusivas para eles aparecerem. E eu importei o jQuery com isso: <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>    no console aparece "nenhum elemento encontrado" no index.html e head.html

Comment: Consegui de outra forma, de vez mandar pegar o conteudo do arquivo html, eu inseri diretamente o html no jQuery: $(function(){
    $('head').append(
  '<link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">'
  );
});

Comment: @Undeath. É a mesma forma só que com conteúdo estático, você estava fazendo algo de errado ao obter o conteúdo via AJAX.

Comment: No arquivo html que eu pedia pra ser coletado, eu colocava o <link> diretamente, sem nada do tipo <html> antes... Será isso?

Comment: Acredito que não @Undeath, faça o seguinte, execute a chama AJAX e imprima o resultado no _console_, para ver se está retornando conforme esperado. Algo assim: `$.get('ajax/test.html', function(data){ console.log(data); });`